# Ruby on Rails | I want to fetch Images of Best Seller Taxonomy from ActiveStorage Title is Fetched and display on Screen But Images are not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, spree

```
<%best_sellers = Spree::Taxonomy.find_by_name("Best Seller").root.products.limit(6)%> 
<%best_sellers.each do |best_seller_array|                                             
   <div class="card card-custom text-center rounded w-25">
     <%= image_tag main_app.url_for(best_seller_array&.attachment),class:"img-fluid" %>
        <a href=""><%= best_seller_array.name%> </a>
   </div>
<%end%>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In spree, product `has_many :images`, so if you want to display any product image, you can try something like below -

```
<%= image_tag main_app.url_for(product&.images&.first&.attachment), class: "img-fluid" %>
```

and if you want to display all the images of the product, then simply traverse the loop of images like below

```
<% best_sellers_products.each do |product| %>
  <% product.images.each do |image| %>
     // display image
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this will solve the problem.

Thank you